# Ubuntu 16.04 Core VM VirtualBox Internal Network Problems

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

in the file /etc/network/interfaces i changed the adapter from the usual

`auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp`

to

`auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
         address 172.16.9.2
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         network 172.16.9.0
         gateway 172.16.9.1
         broadcast 172.16.9.255
         dns-namedservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

so this should auto change enp0s3 to enp0s8 with the proper internal configurations for the network. instead, i get this when i `ip a`

`2 enp0s3:<the usual broadcast multimask......>
         link/ether <mac that ive changed so many times now> brd ffff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

ive rebooted multiple times, nothing.

added in a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-rename-network.rules` with this one line `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="<whatever ive changed the mac addr to>", NAME="enp0s8"`

for my other vms, adding that file and one line worked and changed enp0s3 to enp0s8 and allowed me to talk across my internal network properly. this time it isnt. any suggestions on what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try some other parameters, as stated in [linuxfromscratch.org](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter07/symlinks.html).

I would use the recommended `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file name, and I would try these two additional parameters:

1. `DRIVERS=="?*"`
2. `ATTR{type}=="1"`

In my VirtualBox client (Ubuntu 16.04), adding the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` with:
`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:eb:4d:96", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="enp0s8"` works as expected.

`user@osgeolive:~$ ifconfig -a
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:eb:4d:96

          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc61:f35a:4e30:aecc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4535 (4.5 KB)  TX bytes:3532 (3.5 KB)`